# Handling special characters from Excel to CSV using Python

Tags: python, regex, export-to-csv

Hello am having issues handling a special character from Excel sheet to CSV using python 
when I used

```
else:
                    # Encode strings into format to preserve content of cell
                    row_values.append(cell.value.encode("UTF-8").strip())
```

am getting special character as `'Â'`

and when I use

```
  else:
                    # Encode strings into ISO-8859-1 format to preserve content of cell
                    row_values.append(cell.value.encode("iso-8859-1").strip())
```

am getting Special charater as `'�'` easy to say ? in diamond

i believe it's something to do with encoding but not sure which one to use. these characters are from Excel sheet converted to CSV.

here is the code I used

```
def convert_to_csv(excel_file, input_dir, output_dir):
    """Convert an excel file to a CSV file by removing irrelevant data"""
    try:
        sheet = read_excel(excel_file)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print 'File %s is possibly corrupt. Please check again.' % (excel_file)
        sys.exit(1)
    row_num = sheet.get_highest_row()  # Number of rows
    col_num = sheet.get_highest_column()  # Number of columns
    all_rows = []
    # Loop through rows and columns
    for row in range(row_num):
        row_values = []
        for column in range(col_num):
            # Get cell element
            cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=column)
            # Ignore empty cells
            if cell.value is not None:
                if type(cell.value) == int or type(cell.value) == float:
                    # String encoding not applicable for integers and floating point numbers
                    row_values.append(cell.value)
                else:
                    # Encode strings into ISO-8859-1 format to preserve content of cell
                    row_values.append(cell.value.encode("iso-8859-1").strip())
            else:
                row_values.append('')
        # Append rows only having more than three values each
        if len(set(row_values)-{''}) > 3:
            # print row_values
            all_rows.append(row_values)
    # Saving the data to a csv extension with the same name as the given excel file
    output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, excel_file.split('.')[0] + '.csv')
    with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        writer.writerows(all_rows[1:])
```

using Python 2.6.9
was wondering if we can use regular expresion just before writing to CSV
Is there anyway we can handle this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

well got it fixed

```
           ` else:
                # Encode strings into ISO-8859-1 format to preserve content of cell
                row_values.append(
                    re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', r'', cell.value).strip())`
```